# Why static in C++ gives two different values. At first 5, then 1 after calling the function?

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

The following code of static keyword gives two different output before and after calling a function

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int count=5;
int fun()
{
    count = 0;
    count++;
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d ", count);
    
    printf("%d ", fun());
    printf("%d ", fun());
    printf("%d ", count);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 5 1 1 1

Q) Why is count giving two different values; at first it's 5 then it is 1 after calling the function?

Comment: what else did you expect and why ?

Comment: `fun` modifies `count`. setting it to 0 and then to 1. Before calling `fun` the value of `count` is 5. After it it's 1.

Comment: 1) set count to `0`, 2) increment count, 3) return count.  The "set count to `0`" sets the count to `0`, as it says on the tin.

Comment: Please use the Caps Lock key sparingly.

Comment: @OP Maybe English is not your first language, but capitalizing every letter in the title indicates you are shouting at us.

Comment: You may be thinking that the word "static" here means "constant"?  While that is true in some languages, it's not true in C++.  The keyword `static` has different meanings in C++ based on context (how/where you use it).  You may want to post another question what you think `static` means in a specific C++ context (e.g. cpp file scope vs. class scope).

Answer (score 5):

This

```
int fun()
{
count = 0;
count++;
return count;
}
```

is the same as

```
int fun()
{
    count = 1;
    return count;
}
```

The function assigns `1` to the global `count` and then returns its value.

This

```
static int count=5;
```

initializes the global `count` with the value `5`.

Hence, before calling `fun` the value of `count` is `5`. After calling `fun` the value of `count` is `1`. `fun` always returns `1`, it does not matter how often you call it. And after calling the function the global `count` has the value `1`.

`static` is irrelevant here. The code prints the same when `count` is not declared as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

> WHY COUNT IS GIVING TWO DIFFERENT VALUES AT FIRST 5 THEN AT LAST 1

Because you're calling a function named `fun` that:

a) first reset the `count` to `0`

b) then increment that `count`.

Thus every time you call the function `fun` the `count` is reset to `0` and then incremented to `1` and which is returned by the function.